# Is there a helper method for getting the absolute path to storage directory of masonite?

Tags: masonite

I need to be able to get the absolute path in my controller and my views for a storage path. Some storage paths are different for different static assets in my Masonite application.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2):

Masonite has a helper for this. You can use it directly in your views like this:

Assuming a configuration like this:

```py
DRIVERS = {
    'disk: {
        'location': '/storage/directory'
    }
}
```

You can do this:

```html
<img src="{{ static('disk', 'profile.jpg')">
```

this will result in an output like `/storage/directory/profile.jpg`

Now assuming you had a configuration file like this:

```py
DRIVERS = {
    'disk: {
        'location': {
            'storage': '/storage/directory',
            'uploads': '/storage/uploads',
        }
    }
}
```

You can just slightly modify your static helper:

```
<img src="{{ static('disk.uploads', 'profile.jpg')">
```

**You can also use the helper outside of views by using `from masonite.helpers import static`**